# retrieving technical keys to fact table in PDI

Tags: pentaho, etl, business-intelligence, kettle, datamart

How can I retrieve the technical keys from the dimensions to the fact table in Pentaho Kettle, only the new ones that haven't been loaded yet, I tried to use Dimension Lookup but it didn't worked.

This is my schema :

[image: Star Schema]

I've already created transformations that loads the dimensions directly from a csv file and also a job that executes these transformations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Populating a fact table should be the same as populating a dimension table? You're looking for a step that can convert incoming fields into an sql INSERT query? I've used "Table output" to populate more than 40 fact tables. Works like a charm. If you need something more fancy, "Execute SQL script" works good too.